# CRM Import record in a grid

Tags: import, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

There are 2 scenarios I am looking for help regarding import of records.
1. We have an entity where we need to notify the summary of import results. I pull the import button inside my entity and user is able to import records directly from our entity. The problem is that i wanted to show history of imports in a grid below the information which i cannot get from import system entity. There is one import entity but it shows all the customization etc import records.

1. We have fields on the forms like total numbers imported, Failures etc which are the part of import. I wanted to know how can we pull this import results into our entity?

Thank in advance for your help.

Regards,
MTR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to have the summary of your Imports you can create a CRM-Report for Imports which only selects your specific imports.

Answer (score 0):

with crm 2011, you can not show the list of records not imported,

the import wizard is not very efficient, and does not have a lot of options

in your case, i recommend to use an external tool, like "[kingswaysoft](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/)"

look at this video to know how does it work

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4_E5hGBCFs